# Subir Proyecto Django al CPanel del Servidor

Tags: mysql, django, servidor

Hola cree mi proyecto en django y ya tenia una web, en esta web tengo un enlace que deberia ir al proyecto/admin para loguearse, ya subi la carpeta de mi proyecto y la descomprimi pero cuando le doy clic em dice error 504 no se si es porque mi base de datos aun no tiene esas tablas de django y en ese caso tendria que crear cada una de esas tablas en mi base de datos? yo lo trabaje de forma local con una bse de datos identica pero esas son mis dudas es mi primera vez  con django

Extendere un poco mi pregunta, he visto que existe como un apartado en python en el cpanel, es posible poder instalar un aplicacion desde ahi para poder asi acceder a esta desde mi web? o es obligatorio cambiarme a un servidor que me de soporte con python y django

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo un poco de inforacion que quizas me sea util a ver si entre todos lo podemos hacer

http://blog.elcodiguero.com/python/sitios-web-con-python-virtualenv-y-fastcgi.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/

https://www.hostinet.com/formacion/panel-alojamiento/desplegar-aplicacion-python-cpanel/

Comment: Supongo que tienes las migraciones de las aplicaciones creadas, en ese caso es cuestión de pararte en la raiz del proyecto y typear `python manage.py migrate` y crea las tablas que deba crear

Comment: pero esto lo hago desde mi cpanel? lo que hice fue exportar las tablas pero si puedo hacerlo desde el cpanel lo hago asi no hay problema, no pense que iba a tener problemas con esto :(

Comment: leyendo vi que desde cpanel debo hacerlo con setup python app pero no se coo hacerlo es medio confuso

Comment: Ya veo, bueno en realidad nunca he montado una app con cpanel, creo que vas a necesitar un servidor dedicado en el cual puedas hacerlo, o a menos que te dejen obtener acceso por `ssh` lo cual casi nunca hacen

Comment: buno yo tengo acceso al cpanel y cree una llave ssh , creo pero no se que mas podria hacer y en realidad no hay mucha info jeje , estaba viendo esto https://www.hostinet.com/formacion/panel-alojamiento/desplegar-aplicacion-python-cpanel/ pero no estoy seguro, sigo buscando ya que no quiero pasar todo a algun servidor de heroku o algo asi